# Time complexity of nested for loops with different ranges

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I'm learning about time complexities in my course and I'd like a clarification on the time complexity of the below code:

```
for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n-2):
             //code in constant time
```

I understand that the time complexity of nested for loops of size n is n^2. Would the time complexity of above loop also be n^2?

Comment: Yes it would be `O(n²)` since you have `n*n*1`

Comment: Yes, it would. `-2` is insignificant here.

Comment: When talking about asymptotic complexity(Big-o), we care mainly about magnitude. `-2` won't have any **significant** impact since we take highest term under consideration

Comment: For time complexity think of n as being infinite (or a very very large number). `n-2` becomes `n` (substracting 2 from infinite is insignificant). Even `n^2 + n` becomes `n^2`. (If you have infinite infinites, an extra infinite doesn't add up any complexity to it)

Comment: Or think about the two terms in `n**2 - 2*n`. As `n` gets larger and larger, the ratio `2*n / n**2` becomes closer and closer to zero. So for large `n`, which is what we compare about in asymptotic complexity analysis, the `n**2` is the only part we care about.

Comment: How do we reduce the time complexity for such cases of nested for loops

Comment: Ideally, find a way of performing the task that does not require nested loops. Whether this is possible depends on the specific task. (So if you have a specific task in mind, ask about that specifically.)

Comment: @AbcDef It depends on what the "constant time code" does, but often you simply can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the time complexity of above code will also be O(n^2) as first loop ranges from 0 to n so that gives 'n' but I think you are having difficulty understanding that how it is n^2 as inner loop is of range n-2 but firstly understand Maths behind it, if we see n*(n-2) it gives us n^2 - 2n in this polynomial we see highest power of expression is n^2, so simply for finding time complexity(Especially worst case) we take polynomial's highest degree and also neglect any coefficient with that highest degree.

eg: Let's take another example for your understanding if some complex polynomial like 5n^3 - 3n^2 + 4^n is formed then simply TC(Time complexity) is O(n^3) which is worst case TC.

Hope this helps you in better understanding of topics.

Comment: The difference between worst-case and average-case TC is a separate issue which doesn't really have any relation to the fact we only care about the highest-order term in the polynomial.

Comment: Thank you. This definitely helps. How do we improve the time complexity in such cases of nested for loops

Answer (score 0):

By definition, given two functions `f: R -> R` and `g: R -> R` where `R` denotes the set of real numbers, `f = O(g)` or, what is the same, `f` is said to be `O(g)` if there exist two real numbers `a` and `M` such that for every `x > M` it holds that `f(x) <= a * g(x)`. That being said, it is not hard to see that, since your nested loops perform `n * (n-2) = n^2 - 2n` operations, the time complexity of the code is indeed `O(n^2)`.

Note that, according to the previous definition, it would also be true to say that your code is `O(n^2 - 2n)`. However, it is "irrelevant" to write the non-dominant terms and they are usually omitted. For example, if there is a code that does `n^3 + n^2 -n + 100` basic operations one would just say that it has time complexity `O(n^3)`.